# Make Barcode functionality for Odoo 10 Community Version

Tags: odoo, barcode, odoo-10, warehouse

I want to make a barcode in Inventory picking screen since it's not supported in Odoo 10 Community version.

What do I have to search for, and learn?. I saw the **barcode** module, what the purpose of it and how it can be useful in my case?

In addition I want to make another step in receiving products which is **Put Away**, this step is to put the product on the shelf. To achieve this the warehouse user shall scan the *product barcode* and the scan *location barcode*, after that the system should automatically put that product on scanned location.

Finally please give me any reference or hint that I can start with. And if there is a similar module built before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module has been made and published for free.

[Download](http://arodoo.com/blog/ar-odoo-articles-1/post/warehouse-barcode-module-for-odoo-10-community-version-1)